# data-list-facet, data-facet-value and data-select-single understanding

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, faceted-search

I am an android developer,trying to get started with web development. I have a `filter` which works in `ajax-ish` and displays the result. Please bear with me as I am a complete beginner.

Here is the code:-

```
 <?php foreach (array_keys($statuses) as $key): ?>
                        <?php
                        $status_name = $key;
                        $status_data = $statuses[$key];
                        ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-<?php echo $status_data['id'] ?> " data-list-facet="js-promise-status" data-facet-value="<?php echo $status_name ?>" data-select-single="true" style="background-color: <?php echo $status_data['color_bright'] ?>;  border-color: #333;">
                            <i class="fa fa-<?php echo $status_data['icon'] ?> fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span> <?php echo $status_name ?></span>
                        </button>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

***My problem is***: How are the `data-facet-value`,`data-list-value` and `data-select-single` working to fetch the results?

```
<button class="btn btn-<?php echo $status_data['id'] ?> " data-list-facet="js-promise-status" data-facet-value="<?php echo $status_name ?>" data-select-single="true" style="background-color: <?php echo $status_data['color_bright'] ?>;  border-color: #333;">
```

*Note:- If it is unclear,just make a comment and I will complete it.*